# How to use Coolvetica font in LaTeX for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

How can I use the Coolvetica font within my document? I downloaded the fonts as a .zip file and have to install it and call it using XeLaTex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you download the font, extract the .zip contents to your `~/.fonts` directory and run `fc-cache`.
Then, you can use the `\fontspec` package, loading the font with `\setmainfont{Coolvetica}` (if you want your entire document to use Coolvetica) or `\setsansfont{Coolvetica}` (if you want Coolvetica to appear only when you call `\sffamily`).

Your document should look minimally like this:

```
\documentclass{article} % choose whichever you prefer
\usepackage{fontspec}
% choose one of the following two options
\setmainfont{Coolvetica} % entire document set in Coolvetica
\setsansfont{Coolvetica} % Coolvetica appears only when \sffamily is called
\begin{document}
% voilà
\end{document}
```